# VSCode having multiple types in the configuration

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How would I have a type that requires a boolean or `null`?
The relevant snippet that I was able to one up with:

```json
"something": {
    "type": ["boolean", null],
    "default": true,
}
```

When I used this and tried to change that in vsc, there was only an option to copy that option into the User Settings/Workspace. But, with a boolean type by itself, it'd show `true` or `false` when changing the value. How can I implement this so that when attempting to edit it in the settings, it'd show `true`, `false` or `null` in the edit popup?

EDIT: I was able to get the pop up when using `"enum": [true, false, null]`.  Still curious if there are any other ways.

Answer (score 1):

Use the string `"null"` instead of `null` itself:

```json
"something": {
    "type": ["boolean", "null"],
    "default": true,
}
```

[image]